# How to stop MacOS Document-based App from automatically loading cached file

Tags: xcode, crash, launch, document-based

On launching my app from Xcode, my document-based app **automatically** apparently tries to load a cached document from a previous launch.  That document appears to be corrupted as the app crashes in initWithCoder [which was called from readFromData:].

The solution appears to be to delete the cached documents.  Where are they located and is there anything special about deleting them?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the initWithCoder call which allowed me to launch the app.  Then I opened a file known to be good and quit.  Then I enabled the initWithCoder and launched again.  No problems